# powershell - gives me file list twice

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
# read the HousekeepConfig.csv file and loop through the items
$config = Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Backup\Scripts\HousekeepConfig.csv'
$date = Get-Date  -Format "yyyMMdd_hhmmss"  
Start-Transcript -Path E:\Backup\Housekeep_Log\Housekeep.log
$oldpath = get-location 
$_foldername1 = $item.path.split("\")[-2]
$_foldername2 = $item.path.split("\")[-1]
foreach ($item in $config) 
{
    Write-host $_foldername1 "-" $_foldername2 | Format-table
    if (Test-Path $item.Path -PathType Container) {
        $keep = [int]$item.Keep
        # Use the @() operator to force $files to be an array.
        #Write-host $_foldername1 "-" $_foldername2 | Format-table
        $files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $item.Path -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $item.Regex})
            if ($files.count -gt 0)
            {
                Write-Host "List of Files not deleted"
                Write-output "----------------------------"
                for ($i= ($files.Count - $keep); $i -lt $Files.Length; $i++)
                {
                    #$Files[$i]
                    Write-output $files[$i].fullname
                }
                Write-host "Files to be kept $($item.Keep) is equal to or greater then number of files in folder $($Files.Count), so keeping all "
                Write-output "----------------------------"
                if (($files.Count - $keep) -gt 0) 
                {
                    # reduce the array to contain only the number of files in $keep
                    $files = $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First $keep
                    #Write-Output "----------------------------"
                    Write-Output "List of Deleted Files from " $files.path
                    Write-output "----------------------------"
                    Write-Output $files.FullName | format-table
                    Write-output "------------------"
                    #$date,"List of Files Deleted" $files.FullName | Add-Content -Path 'E:\backup\housekeep_log\Housekeep.log' #-verboes
                    #$files | Remove-Item -Force
                }
                else { }
            }
        else {
            Write-host $_foldername1 "-" $_foldername2 | Format-table
            Write-Warning "Folder $($item.Path) not valid"
            Write-output "------------------"
        }
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
Rename-Item E:\Backup\Housekeep_Log\Housekeep.log 
E:\Backup\Housekeep_Log\HousekeepLog_$date.log
write-host Log File has been created and  renamed to HousekeepLog_$date.log

set-location $oldpath
```

using above code but it gives me display like below, so unable to figure out why it displays the same files twice?

> ### JIRA - logs List of Files not deleted
>
> C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\localhost.2022-08-02.log
>
> C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\localhost.2022-08-03.log
>
> C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\localhost.2022-08-02.log
>
> C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\localhost.2022-08-03.log

Files to be kept 30 is equal to or greater then number of files in folder 2, so keeping all

My CSV File:

```
"Name","Path","Keep","Regex"
"Bitbucket - Export - Backup Files","C:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bitbucket\export","7","^backup.*.zip"
"Bitbucket - Audit - Logs","C:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bitbucket\log\audit","30","^atlassian-bitbucket-audit-"
"Bitbucket - Logs","C:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bitbucket\log","30","^atlassian-bitbucket-2"
"Bitbucket - Access - Logs","C:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bitbucket\log","30","^atlassian-bitbucket-access-"
"Bitbucket - Backup Files","C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0\backups","7","^bitbucket.*.tar"
"Confluence - Backup Files","E:\Backup\Confluence","7","^backup.*.zip"
"Confluence - Catalina - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence\logs","30","^catalina.*log"
"Confluence - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence\logs","30","^confluence"
"Confluence - Daemon - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence\logs","30","^commons-daemon"
"Confluence - GC - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence\logs","30","^gc-"
"JIRA - Export files","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA\export","5","^zip"
"JIRA - Catalina - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^catalina.*log"
"JIRA - Access - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^access.*log"
"JIRA - GC - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^atlassian-jira-gc"
"JIRA - Daemon - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^commons-daemon"
"JIRA - Software - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^jirasoftware"
"JIRA - Localhost - Logs","C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs","30","^localhost"
```

Comment: managed to figure the issue... is due to foreach ($item in $config) loop....

Comment: ah... i was incorrect... it required that foreach () loop. so now not sure why it is is displaying list of files twice.

Comment: In your `$_foldername1` and `$_foldername2` you're referencing `$item` which isn't declared till after in your `foreach` loop. Why? Also, since you're iterating through your csv, if any criteria matches your RegEx twice, it'll display the same file twice.

Comment: I have changed $_foldername1 & $_foldername2 content in my CSV files, so getting values from the CSV files instead looking into the path.
hummmm... about the logic you stated... how do i stop that? is there any switch like taking -unique values

Comment: have added my CSV filed in the post.

Comment: is there any solutions you could suggest @abraham zinala

Comment: There doesn't seem much to be wrong. I would comment out all the code except that specific part and run it again to see if you get the same results.\

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have tried but still unable to figure out why?

Comment: unless you're actually removing the files, some will show as duplicate from your first `foreach` loop. You nmay have more than one of the same in your csv. I still don't understand the purpose of `$item.path.split("\")[-1]`, since, it's not been defined till after in your foreach loop

Comment: managed to fix the problem of question listed at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129583461?noredirect=1 but unable to find out for the above listed question.... when ran the query on my desktop couldn't replicate. So wondering why